# Abrir Form Via ContexMenuStrip, evento click de valor aleatório

Tags: c#, datagridview, context-menu

Estou com o seguinte problema:

Tenho 2 form `FrmCadastroPessoa` e `FrmCadEscala`.

Em `FrmCadastroPessoa` tenho o `DataGridView` mostrado, quando eu clico com o botão direito em uma *Cell*, lista as escalas que a pessoa está cadastrada.

Mas essas lista de escala são geradas em tempo de execução, a cada *click* do *mouse*, eu limpo (`.Clear()`) o `ContexMenuStrip` e adiciono as escalas que vieram do `Select`.

Como eu consigo chamar o `FrmCadEscala` e passar o **ID** da pessoa para seu construtor?

A pergunta é, como vou gerar o evento `Click`(do `ContexMenuStrip`) de algo que eu não sei o nome nem quantos vai ter?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
public frmCadEscala()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Atualizar();
}

public frmCadEscala(int id)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Atualizar(id);
}
```

Código do evento click no DataGridView

```
 
private void dgvPessoa_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.RowIndex == -1)
            {
                return;
            }
            cmsListarEscala.Items.Clear();
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
```

`{
            // para não precisar fazer outro select, coloquei se a imagem for cancel(não tem escala) então não exibe
            if (dgvPessoa.Rows[dgvPessoa.CurrentRow.Index].Cells["ESCALA"].Value == global::Row.Properties.Resources.Cancel_32x32)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                int n = e.RowIndex;
                int m = dgvPessoa.Rows[e.RowIndex.toInt32()].Cells["ID"].Value.toInt32();
                DataTable DTE = this.e.BuscarTodasEscalasPessoa(dgvPessoa.Rows[e.RowIndex.toInt32()].Cells["ID"].Value.toInt32());
                if (DTE != null)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < DTE.Rows.Count; i++)// coloco as escalas no CMSListarEscala
                    {
                        cmsListarEscala.Items.Add(DTE.Rows[i]["ESCALA"].ToString());

                    }
                    cmsListarEscala.Show(MousePosition); // exibo

                }
            }
        } else
        {
            return;
        }`

Comment: Por favor, poste o código em texto ao invés de imagens.

Comment: A ideia será clicar, por exemplo, na opção `3 VENDA` e abrir o `FrmCadEscala` com o ID da linha selecionada?

Comment: João Martins, Sim.
Mas tem um problema o '3 venda' é uma escala da linha clicada, eu adiciono ele em tempo de execução, como vou gerar o evento click dela,
Sendo que ela é gerada de acordo com cada pessoa?

Comment: Essa linha `int m = dgvPessoa.Rows[e.RowIndex.toInt32()].Cells["ID"].Value.toInt32(); ` não coloca em  `m` o `ID` que você quer passar para o constructo do formulário `frmCadEscala`?

Comment: Sim, eu consegui, descobri que posso usar o método Click do CMS e filtrar o nome do item selecionado, então passo o Nome do item para o construtor, pesquiso pelo id do nome e abro o FrmCadEscala do jeito que eu queria, eu usei isso apenas para ver se estava vindo o ID mesmo kkk, onde fecho a pergunta?